# How do I skip xslt code when xml condition is true?

Tags: xslt

What I want to do is skip the XSLT code if my condition is true. My condition is if xml **ControlPoint  @UserID='Moo" and if ControlPoint= Save-Event or  *Save-Sentence** skip the xslt code I have here below. 
***How do I do the if statement or choose?***

**My xslt code**

```
<?altova_samplexml c:\TEMP\temp11.xml?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="Integration/Case"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

**Here is the code I want to skip or not execute when the above 3 conditions are true** 
**If the above 3 conditions are not true, then this code is executed.**

```
<!-- Check for Case event updates that should trigger a pass -->    
<xsl:if test="//Integration/ControlPoint='SAVE-EVENT'">
<!-- Check for Discharge from Probation.  Return whether or not BCA case or Charges Disposed -->
    <xsl:for-each select="CaseEvent[(EventType/@Word='DISCHPROB')]">
        <xsl:variable name="vEditCode">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@Op='A'">A</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(@Op='E') and (Deleted='true')">D</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@Op='E'">E</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($vEditCode) > 0">
        <NotificationEvent notificationType="BCADisposition">
            <xsl:attribute name="bcaCaseIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="$vBCACase"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="allChargesDisposedIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="$vAllChargesDisposed"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="elementKey"><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="editCode"><xsl:value-of select="$vEditCode"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:text>CASE-EVENT-DISCHPROB</xsl:text>
        </NotificationEvent>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- Check for repass events -->
    <!-- -->
    <xsl:if test="count(CaseEvent[(@Op='A') and (count(EventGroups/EventGroup[@Word='CCHSPECIAL'])!=0)])!=0">
        <NotificationEvent notificationType="BCADisposition">
            <xsl:attribute name="bcaCaseIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="$vBCACase"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="allChargesDisposedIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="$vAllChargesDisposed"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="elementKey"><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:text>COURT-DATA-NOT-ORIGINALLY-PASSED</xsl:text>
        </NotificationEvent>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:if>
```

**Here is the xml document that has the UserID="MOO, and ControlPoint = SAVE-EVENT**
So code above in this case should be skipped and not processed by **XSLT code**

**XML Document**

```
<Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="Disposition BCA Event" MessageID="65791751" xmlns="">
    <ControlPoint Timestamp="11/6/2014 2:27:39 PM" UserID="MOO">SAVE-EVENT</ControlPoint>
    <Case Op="E" InternalID="1617083662" ID="12116060" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
</Integration>
```

Comment: The template match the document node, also sometimes called root node. Document nodes don't have any attribute nodes so a check of `@UserID` in the context of document node does not make any sense. Consider to post a sample of the input XML you have and the output you want to create. What do you want to do in the case of the exit, not even create a result document with the transformation?

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Integration[not(ControlPoint/@UserID='MOO' and (ControlPoint='SAVE-EVENT' or ControlPoint='SAVE-SENTENCE'))]/Case"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Case">
    <!-- code to apply -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: XML is case-sensitive; "Moo" is not the same thing as "MOO".

Comment: This is only working when @UserID='MOO' and ControlPoint=SAVE-SENTENCE'.     **When my xml has @UserID='MOO' and ControlPoint='SAVE-EVENT' it is not working**